# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show a list of `mssg`, but I get the following error:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

```
@foreach ($mssg as $mssg)
      <tr>
    <td>{{$mssg["objMessage"]}}</td>
    <td>{{ $mssg["estDateMessage"]  }}  </td>
    <td>
        @if($mssg["active"]==0)
         {{"message non lue"}}
        @else
         {{"messaage lue"}}
        @endif
    </td>
    <td><button><a href="/mssg">lire</a></button></td>
    <td><button>delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

This is my controller

```
function indexe() { 
    $x = Auth::User()->id;
    $mess = Auth::User()->name;
    $mssg = messages::find($x);

    foreach($mssg as $m) {
        dd($m["idUser"]); 
    }

    return view('liate_message',["mssg"=>$mssg],["idd"=>$mess]);
}
```

Comment: So what does `dd($m["idUser"]); ` print?

Answer (score -1):

Check your `foreach code`

`@foreach ($mssg as $mssg)`
change to
`@foreach ($mssg as $m)`

then change all entries like `{{$mssg["objMessage"]}}` to `{{$m["objMessage"]}}`

You can change the `$m` to any variable names you want.

Comment: still same erreue

Answer (score -2):

Make sure variable `$mssg` => not null and is_array.

You should `dd` the `$mssg` variable in the controller to check what it is, before returning `$mssg` to the view.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer